# Jekyll: Use an include from content

Tags: jekyll

How can I use a short include in Jekyll's content (not in the template files) and have it rendered?

For **example** inside a page content or post I want to write something like this:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.*

```
{% include responsive_youtube.html video="nGeKSiCQkPw" %}
```

*Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum*

If I do it now Jekyll does not process the snippet it just posts the code. It works in template files but not as content. I'm using html with font matter code (and not markdown) as content.

Answer (score 0):

[Jekyll YouTube Embed Plugin](https://gist.github.com/joelverhagen/1805814) can do it ! And you can find other plugins on the [Jekyll plugins section](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/).

Note that you cannot use this plugin with github pages.

This video is excellent !

```
{% youtube nGeKSiCQkPw %}
```

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid Youtube was an example, not the real problem. The real problem is hard to explain. I'm not a Ruby dev but if there's no other way I'll try to build a plugin from the Youtube one.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely know that it's possible to use includes in the content, I made a site with Jekyll where I'm doing it exactly like this:

```
some text

{% include whatever.html %}

more text
```

---

The question is why it doesn't work for you.

You say you aren't using Markdown, but maybe the file still has the `.md` extension *(even if you're using no Markdown inside, only HTML)*?
If yes, Jekyll *will* treat it as Markdown.

I suspect that you indented the `{% include...` line like this:

```
some text

    {% include whatever.html %}

more text
```

If yes, the Markdown parser will treat it as code.
Jekyll will still process the include and inject the HTML from the include file, but the HTML will not be rendered, but displayed as code because of the indentation.

---

If that doesn't help, you need to show us some actual source code.

Comment: Sure, I tried here https://github.com/osvik/m-templates/blob/gh-pages/one/index.html . Please note the pages are not rendered in Github but on my local machine, a Mac with Jekyll 2.1.1 Again please note Youtube was an example.

Comment: I don't see any includes in that file. Did you really try to put `{% include whatever.html %}` into that file (`/one/index.html `)?